# How can I uninstall ruby on rails completely on Windows (installed using RailsInstaller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a complete beginner to ruby on rails and am just following a tutorial on Skillshare. I installed rails on Windows 7 following the instruction, but have been having issues.

I'd like to uninstall it completely and start fresh.

I saw some posts related to this, but commands like gem uninstall rails don't work because I'm not sure which folder I should be in when I type in that command.

Also, the tutorial is being done in Mac so I'm having trouble following it exactly.

Please let me know if there's a way to uninstall rails (installed using railsinstaller). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Don't bother about cleaning up the previous rails installation. At least for now. Since you want to start fresh, I would suggest you start with [Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial) - it is very comprehensive, covers everything a newcomer needs to work with RoR, is up-to-date, and is available for free online.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I will certainly read the tutorial you mentioned but I'd like to learn as I build something (project based learning works better for me). But as I build my test app out, I will go through that tutorial as well.

Answer (score 10):

You can uninstall it from `Program and Features` in Control Panel. After that you can remove the directory to which you installed it. If you didn't change it, then it is `C:\Program Files(x86)\Railsinstaller`

However, refreshing the software installation is just about the extreme step. What issues are you experiencing? You can comment or add those to your questions.

Comment: Actually RailsInstaller installs in `C:\RailsInstaller`, installation inside a folder with spaces is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks Luis. I change all my installations to a separate directory and forgot what railsinstaller installs in. Perhaps installation in directory with spaces is the problem here.

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to still remove it and start fresh because I've installed a lot of things and now it won't even tell me rails version. But I will reinstall it and if the problem persists, I will post it here.

Comment: ruby wont make friends with sqlite3. thats my reason to quit ruby once for all